# How do I draw text using the Canvas in a master-detail application?

Tags: android

I wanted to play with android, and so I took some of my existing and modified it. It's a master-detail application, generated in Eclipse using the default settings and no new files. I took the code of the ItemDetailFragment.java located in com.. and modified it so it would draw some test on the screen at (0,0)

Here's the code I modified

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
                container, false);
        //customImageView custom = (customImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            //((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail_)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ((customImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail__)).invalidate();
        }
        return rootView;
    }
    private class customImageView extends View {
    /*To clarify I added this class myself b/c the android developer guide on Canvas and Drawables says to*/

        public customImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawText("Some Example Text", 0, 0, new Paint());
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and here's my /res/layout/fragment_item_detail.xml with the declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >


     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/item_detail"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="16dp"
       android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<!-- Autogenerated -->

<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/item_detail_"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <!--  android:src="@drawable/android" /> -->
    <!-- I added this in -->

<customImageView
      android:id="@+id/item_detail__"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <!-- This is the relevant part, I added this in -->

</LinearLayout>
```

However when the app is run on an emulator I get [this big list of errors](http://pastebin.com/UBJRLhWs)

Could someone please help me to understand why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your View class is private, try setting it to public. Also, when adding a custom view on the XML you need to include the full location of it, so if it is inside a Class called clazz on package com.pkg, you need to write

```
    <com.pkg.clazz.customImageView
       ... />
```